# android ndk создать папку cache

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

Мне нужно создать папку cache. Сейчас я делаю так:

```
system("mkdir /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/имя пакета/cache");
```

Есть ли другой способ без использования функций java?

Comment: Представленный кусок кода не создает никаких папок.

Comment: @user7860670, извиняюсь, поправил.

Comment: Папки для кеша обычно создаются системой автоматически и путь к ним можно получить посредством методов `android.content.Context.getCacheDir` или `android.content.Context.getExternalCacheDir`, которыми и надо пользоваться.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28120447/5479247